# Fetch list of likes using FQL with PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get a list of tv shows that a user has liked on Facebook (with a comma between them).
The code below only shows the last array, however if I do it using "print_r($fqlResults)" it shows all of the arrays.

```
$fql = "SELECT name, type FROM page WHERE type IN ('TV SHOW') AND page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me())";

$fqlResults = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' =>$fql,
));
foreach( $fqlResults as $keys => $values ){
    $tvShows = $values[name];
}
```

Any responses will be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not PHP, but your query string gave me exactly what I needed to get a user's page-LIKEs -- thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FQL query is correct.  But your PHP code's foreach is not concatenating anything.

You should use the implode function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
<?php

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

// Empty string when using an empty array:
var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""

?>
```